# reverse array method not working

Tags: java

Why doesn't this work, but when I move the for loop from the main method to the reverse method it does?

```
public class ReverseArray
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        reverse(list);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void reverse(int[] list)
    {
        int[] temp = new int[list.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = list[(list.length - 1) - i];
        }

        list = temp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are making changes to list which are internal to the method reverse.Instead you should have return the updated list as h shown in example or update the original list itself

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

    int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    list=reverse(list);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }
    }

public static int[] reverse(int[] list)
{
    int[] temp = new int[list.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = list[(list.length - 1) - i];
        //list[i]=temp[i];

    }

    list = temp;
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't update the callers array reference from your method (and you don't need to). Instead iterate half-way through the list and swap each element with the position like,

```
public static void reverse(int[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length / 2; i++) {
        int t = list[(list.length - 1) - i];
        list[(list.length - 1) - i] = list[i];
        list[i] = t;
    }
}
```

Also, you could print your array with [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    reverse(list);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
}
```

Output is

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `list` in the `reverse` method only exists for the lifetime of the method. You need to either return the new reverse list and assign it to a variable (example below), or modify the original list itself (Elliott Frisch's answer).

```
public class ReverseArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        list = reverse(list);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] reverse(int[] list) {
        int[] temp = new int[list.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = list[(list.length - 1) - i];
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return a value from your method i.e.

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] list)  {
    ...
    return temp;
}
```

and in main...

```
list = reverse(list);
```

instead of

```
reverse(list);
```